# How to make the addon in bootstrap stay while the parent is expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

What I did was to limit the size of the dropdown list of a selectbox to 8 by using javascript to make the dropdown short.

My problem is when i click the selectbox the Birthday also expand. How do i prevent the addon Birthday from expading while I'm selecting from the selectbox?

The problem starts when i put a javascript inside my selectbox to make the drop downbox short:

here is the script i put in the selectbox:

```
 onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;"
```

current output: http://jsfiddle.net/3Xahs/1/

[image]

html:

```
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-12">
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                <div class="btn-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Birthday</span>
                        <select name="month" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;" class="btn btn-default" id="bmonth" data-container="body" data-placement="left" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Select your Birthday!" >
                        <option value="">Month</option>

                        </select>
                        <select name="day" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;" class="btn btn-default" id="bday" data-container="body" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Select your Birthday!" >
                        <option value="">Day</option>

                        </select>
                        <select name="year" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}"  onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;" class="btn btn-default" id="byear" data-container="body" data-placement="right" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Select your Birthday!" >
                        <option value="">Year</option>

                        </select>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var month = [], day = [], year = [];

            for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
                month.push(i);
            }
            for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
                day.push(i);
            }
            for (var i = 1900; i <= (new Date().getFullYear()); i++) {
                year.push(i);
            }
            $.each(day, function (index, d) {
                $("#bday").append("<option value = '"+d+"'>"+d+"</option>");
            });
            $.each(month, function (index, m) {
                $("#bmonth").append("<option value = '"+m+"'>"+m+"</option>");
            });
            $.each(year, function (index, y) {
                $("#byear").append("<option value = '"+y+"'>"+y+"</option>");
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `span` with the text `Birthday` is an in-line element which ignores height and width by default and fills the available space.

One way to work around it without changing the actual DOM structure is to apply a `display: block` for example and and give it a `height`, `width` and in your case a `float: left` as well, similar to this:

```
.fixedSize{
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    height: 32px;
    float: left;
}
```

Assign the class to the span, like this:

```
<span class="input-group-addon fixedSize">Birthday</span>
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GZSH6/) - Applying height and width to the span element

---

This is only one way but you can also wrap a div around it instead but you would need to apply CSS similar to the above then anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure where the HTML is coming from (or more correctly, how much of it you can modify) but if you move the <kbd>SPAN</kbd> element out of main container and display it 'inline' it's able to work without expansion:

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-12">
    <!-- NOTE: This is where the 'Birthday' element was moved up to -->
    <span class="input-group-addon">Birthday</span>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
        <div class="btn-group input-group">
            <select name="month" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;" class="btn btn-default" id="bmonth" data-container="body" data-placement="left" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Select your Birthday!">
                <option value="">Month</option>
            </select>
            <select name="day" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;" class="btn btn-default" id="bday" data-container="body" data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Select your Birthday!">
                <option value="">Day</option>
            </select>
            <select name="year" onmousedown="if(this.options.length>8){this.size=8;}" onchange='this.size=0;' onblur="this.size=0;" class="btn btn-default" id="byear" data-container="body" data-placement="right" data-toggle="popover" data-content="Select your Birthday!">
                <option value="">Year</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the corresponding CSS:

```
span.input-group-addon {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    width: 30%;
}
```

**JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MasterXen/v79KW/1/**